# Wordpress Admin Navigation Bugging Out

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with Wordpress's admin panel. The CSS seems to be bugging out for some reason. I haven't touched the core files at all. It looks like this when I click a link like "posts" or "pages", etc. If I refresh the page, it goes back to looking normal. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any help would be awesome. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a WordPress bug, it is a Chrome bug.

You can follow the ticket tracker **[here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33199)**

There are a couple of workarounds to fix this until the new Chrome version arrives.

Add the follow hook via your `functions.php` file or using a plugin.

**Workaround 1**

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chrome_fix');
function chrome_fix() {
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome' ) !== false )
        wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }' );
}
```

**[Source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33199#comment:43)**

**Workaround 2**

> In Chrome, go to chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint 
>   Enable the "disable slimming paint" setting and ensure that the "enable-slimming-paint" setting immediately below it is not turned on. 
>   Chrome will need to Relaunch to save the setting. Once you have done so, the bug is gone.

**[Source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33199#comment:45)**

Comment: Finally found a solution for this issue. Thanks ;) You've got my +1.

Comment: Thanks, this at least makes me feel better that it's limited to a browser, so I can explain that to the client. I prefer the second workaround though. Prefer not to add code if not 100% necessary. I do however feel like this is a Wordpress bug, in that Wordpress should ensure crossbrowser compatibility, especially for a feature this obvious.